# Hold Kernel for Custom Kernel

Tags: kernel, upgrade

I have built a custom kernel which I want to install. I am afraid that the next upgrade will overwrite my custom kernel. Do I have to put the current kernel on hold or is this not necessary? I cannot find a hint in the many description of how to build a custom kernel.

The current kernel is:

```
# uname -r
4.4.0-59-generic
```

The custom kernel debs are:

```
linux-headers-4.4.35-custom_4.4.35-custom-1_i386.deb
linux-image-4.4.35-custom_4.4.35-custom-1_i386.deb
linux-image-4.4.35-custom-dbg_4.4.35-custom-1_i386.deb
linux-libc-dev_4.4.35-custom-1_i386.deb
```

Comment: If it and its initrd have different filenames in `/boot` and if its modules are under a different directory in `/lib/modules` than any of the other installed kernels, then you will be fine.

Comment: I have updated the question. Is this enough to say which case it is?

Comment: Kernel cant be upgraded.Kernel should be installed.Because You have a different sub version of kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package manager will not overwrite your kernel. Actually, package manager never overwrite any kernel, it just add new version parallel to existing versions on system.
Depending on distribution, package manager may initiate reconfiguration of boot loader on your system upon installing new or removing existing kernel, but that's really distribution specific. (Ubuntu does exactly that) In that case, after installing new version of kernel, it will be default on startup, so you will have to manually change boot loader config so your custom version would be default choice.

Comment: Ok I ubnderstand the following: I have my “normal” kernels and I install my custom kernel. When I put the “normal” kernel on hold no upgrade will change the “normal” kernel and I’ll always work with my custom kernel.

Comment: yes, as short answer. But keep mind on the fact that new kernel version often fix security issues. So it would be wise to save your custom kernel config file and use it for new kernel compilation occasionally with source code of new kernel version.